# Can't change the style of an element in querySelectorAll results

Tags: html, typescript, dom, dom-manipulation

I'm trying to edit the style of a div on page in order to hide it.  I'm able to something like this

```
  let mainPanelFirstChild = document.getElementById("jp-main-content-panel")
    .children[0];
  (mainPanelFirstChild as HTMLElement).style.display = "none";
```

with elements that have id attributes, but the element I want to hide does not have an id attribute.

Here's the code that doesn't work as expected:

```
    const closeIconNodeList = document.querySelectorAll(
      ".p-TabBar-tabCloseIcon"
    );
    closeIconNodeList.forEach((node) => {
      console.log(node);
      (node as HTMLElement).style.display = "none";
    });
```

`console.log` shows the element as I would expect it to, however changing the `style.display` attribute does nothing.  I have tried looping over `document.querySelectorAll` with a typical for loop to address the elements directly.  That did nothing either.

Comment: Revisiting some of my old answers. @wes - if this helped solve your problem, can you kindly mark this answer correct by clicking the checkmark? It will help others who have similar issues in the future. - Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

I've used some of your code to create a working snippet of what you may be trying to accomplish.

EDIT: updated snippet to use loop instead

```js
//if you choose to use querySelectorAll then you must either target a specific element or loop through the available elements that you want to target with class ".p-TabBar-tabCloseIcon"

//if you are only targeting one element then use document.querySelector instead

//here we will use querySelectorAll like in your example
var closeIconNodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".p-TabBar-tabCloseIcon");

//below I have created a loop to check the amount of elements in the array that is output using querySelectorAll

//the hideMe function will hide all elements in the array that use class "p-Tabbar-tabCloseIcon" 
const hideMe = function() {
for (var x = 0; x < closeIconNodeList.length; x++)
    closeIconNodeList[x].style.display = 'none';
 };
```

```html
<div class="p-TabBar-tabCloseIcon">Hide me</div>
<div class="p-TabBar-tabCloseIcon">Hide me 2</div>
<div class="p-TabBar-tabCloseIcon">Hide me 3</div>
<button onclick="hideMe();">Click To Hide</button>
```

Comment: This is not with typescript though. @wes was using typescript